# Instaling Logitech Squeezebox server

Tags: server, logitech

I need help installing the Logitech Squeezebox server in Ubuntu 14.  I downloaded the Linux version from Logitech and see a squeezebox folder in the etc folder.  After reboot. The next instruction is to type "service squeezeboxserver start" in the terminal.  Typing as is or preceded by sudo gets me a"unrecognized service".  Not sure what to do at this point.  The Logictech instructions are here: http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17011/related/1

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `service logitechmediaserver start`. The name has changed, but not all documentation is up to date. There is a script called logitechmediaserver in your /etc/init.d/ folder. The name was changed starting with version 7.7.0.

Comment: Thanks, that at least show a dialog that indicated the server may be starting but then trying http://127.0.0.1:9000/ still does not connect.  BTW: I also run the Window version when I boot into Win 7 so I do know that I can connect.  From reading forums, there seems to be a Perl issue regarding version 5, does this apply possibly?

Comment: If there is a Perl issue you may take a look at the server log. Also, the server may take some time to start up. Use `netstat -a` to see if there is a service listening on port 9000 (and 9090 for the command line interface).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see 9000 or 9090 from a rather long list and assuming that the last column are the ports.  Thanks

Comment: Any Perl problems should show up in `/var/log/squeezeboxserver/server.log`.